# Why does the browser not display the site when going through the domain (it works if you go through example.com:8000 or 111.111.111.111)?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to set up nginx inside docker.
However, I ran into a problem, when going to example.com, the browser does not display the site. But if I go to the ip address (for example 111.111.111.111) or try to go to the site through the port: example.com:8000, then everything works. How to solve this problem?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  postgresql:
    build:
      context: ./docker/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
  django:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    restart: unless-stopped
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - django
    restart: unless-stopped
```

docker/nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:8000;
    }
}
```

docker/nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: where have you hosted this? are the A record settings set for the domain in cpanel?

Comment: sounds like your DNS entries are not ready yet, or misconfigured

Comment: @deechris27 
I host it at DigitalOcean. Type: A Hostname: example.com Value: directs to 111.111.111.111 TTL (seconds): 3600